# Export data to Excel from DataGridView in 2 Tab Control C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to ask something I can't figure out how to fix it.

Please help me, so I need to develop an app meanwhile it's been ready to export to excel, but this app only can export the file one by one of the Tabs, so I need to join them manually, I need to know how to make it to be just 1 file and maybe can be 2 sheets excel file,

Thanks

```
private void DOCUMENT_GENERATOR(object sender, string DocPath)
{
    try
    {
        foreach string DateTimeID = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMMdd}", DateTime.Now) + "_" + string.Format("{0:hhmmss}", DateTime.Now);
        var resul = from c in Class.TreeMenusCls.items where c.ID.ToString() == treeView1.SelectedNode.Name select new { c.ID, c.MenuName, c.ParentID, c.Tag, c.CreateCtl, c.HeaderOnly };
        foreach (var cat in resul)
        {
            var get_query = from s in QueryCollectionTable.Select() where Convert.ToInt16(s["KEY_MENUS"]) == MenuIDSelected orderby s["PRIORITY"] select s;
            foreach (var Eq in get_query)
            {
                TabControl Tab;
                Tab = (TabControl)this.Controls.Find("Tab" + Eq["KEY_MENUS"], true)[0];
                Control.ControlCollection SearchCtl = Tab.TabPages[Convert.ToInt16(Eq["PRIORITY"])].Controls;

                foreach (Control c in SearchCtl)
                {
                    if (c.Name == "Grid" + Eq["NO_ID"])
                    {
                        Thread[] Tr = new Thread[0];
                        Array.Resize(ref Tr, Tr.Length + 1);

                        int priority = Convert.ToInt16(Eq["PRIORITY"]);
                        string query_name = Eq["QUERY_NAME"].ToString();
                        string menu_name = cat.MenuName;
                        int formated = Convert.ToInt16(Eq["FORMATED"]);
                        string row_start = Eq["ROW_START"].ToString();
                        string draft_location = Eq["DRAFT_LOCATION"].ToString();
                        string run_macro_name = Eq["RUN_MACRO_NAME"].ToString();

                        if (sender == EXCEL_CMD_GENERATE)
                        {
                            if (formated == 0)
                                Tr[Tr.Length - 1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { this.Obj[0].ExcelGenerator((DataGridView)c, Tab, priority, query_name, menu_name, DateTimeID, DocPath); }));
                            else if (formated == 1)
                                Tr[Tr.Length - 1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { this.Obj[0].ExcelFormated((DataGridView)c, Tab, priority, query_name, menu_name, DateTimeID, DocPath, formated, row_start, draft_location, run_macro_name); }));
                        }
                        if (sender == TEXT_CMD_GENERATE)
                            Tr[Tr.Length - 1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { this.Obj[0].TextGenerator((DataGridView)c, Tab, priority, query_name, menu_name, DateTimeID, DocPath); }));
                        if (sender == CSV_CMD_GENERATE)
                            Tr[Tr.Length - 1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { this.Obj[0].CsvGenerator((DataGridView)c, Tab, priority, query_name, menu_name, DateTimeID, DocPath); }));
                        if (sender == XML_CMD_GENERATE)
                            Tr[Tr.Length - 1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { this.Obj[0].XmlGenerator((DataGridView)c, Tab, priority, query_name, menu_name, DateTimeID, DocPath); }));
                        Tr[Tr.Length - 1].Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: then, show us some of your code maybe?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0):

For export any data to excel, you can use ClosedXML.Report.
It is a tool for report generation with which you can easily export any data from your .NET classes to Excel using a XLSX-template.

See more here https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report

Comment: i know about it before but i cant change the app code, i just can add some feature without lost other